# Copy only selected range of the row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace "EntireRow.Copy" to only copy the range of columns F:AB.

Currently my code: `xRg(K).EntireRow.CopyDestination:=`

Copies the whole row. How can I have it select only the desired range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this with a delete function I have:

sht.Range(col1 & ":" & col2).delete

You could modify it to do this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:C1").Value=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C1").Value
```

You'd obviously need to swap out A1:C1 with variables based on some criteria. But that will set a range of cells equal to another range

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `xRg` is a range (please post more code)

```
Range(Cells(xRg(K).Row, "F"), Cells(xRg(K).Row, "AB")).Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the below you copy from row 1 to row 10 of columns F:AB

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(.Cells(1, "F"), .Cells(10, "AB")).Copy
    End With

End Sub
```